# Не появляется значок настроек на панели действий

Tags: android, menu, android-toolbar

Я уже читал на форуме о похожих проблемах и их решениях, но на данный момент эти решения не помогают. Поэтому я обращаюсь к вам за помощью, я оставляю свой код. Я новичок пишу этот проект по разным источникам, это первый проект такой сложности для меня, поэтому в процессе я учусь и сталкиваюсь с разными трудностями. Заранее спасибо за любые советы.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private TabsAccesorAdapter tabsAccesorAdapter;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        //мы передаем в ActionBar виджет toolbar
        setActionBar(toolbar);
        //добавим
        getActionBar().setTitle("");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_pager);
        tabsAccesorAdapter = new TabsAccesorAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAccesorAdapter);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu,menu);

       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
         super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_find_people){

         }
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_create_group){

        }
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_settings){

        }
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_logout){
           mAuth.signOut();
           Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this,WelcomeActivity.class);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_app_bar"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chat"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        />
</android.widget.Toolbar>
```

options_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
<item
    android:title="Searching"
    android:id="@+id/menu_find_people"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    >
</item>
    <item
        android:title="New group"
        android:id="@+id/menu_create_group"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        >
    </item>
    <item
        android:title="Settings"
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        >
    </item>
    <item
        android:title="Logout"
        android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        >
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: У вас прям в самой Android Studio на панели значек не появляется?

Comment: В приложении не появляется.

Comment: android-studio здесь не при чем!!!! просьба не использовать эту метку в вопросах не связанных непосредственно с самой IDE

Comment: ok, а метка не означает, что я про  проблему с IDE

Comment: а при чем здесь IDE? если вы вместо гвоздя пытаетесь забить саморез, вы же не говорите что проблема в молотке?) вот подобный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090542/add-a-menu-to-an-empty-activity попробуйте. так же желательно использовать один источник кода который будет приведен в вопросе

Comment: Посмотрите в примере как переопределяются соответсвующие методы в активити. У вас код написан по-другому, возможно тут и будет источник проблемы. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: не сработало "developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus "